# Listview sometimes null when I use gettag

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a problem with my view in Android. I use a GridView with items inside it. Each item does have a name, button,description and icon. But each item also has a listview. When I click on the button I want to show the listview that is linked to that button.

On startup it works, but when I scroll up and down a few times my listview either doesn't show or it shows the wrong listview.

I have read alot of other questions and articles, but I cant find the thing I am doing wrong.

Also tried something like this but that still gives the same result

```
if (convertView == null){             
    holder = new new ListHolder();
    convertView.setTag(holder);                                         
} 
else {
    holder = (ListHolder) convertView.getTag();               
}
```

The getView

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ListHolder holder;
        HarmonicaItem harmonicaItem = ((MainActivity) context).getHarmonicaItems().get(position);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        }

        holder = new ListHolder();
        holder.logo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        holder.line = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line);
        holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button);
        holder.listView = (ListView) row.findViewById(R.id.subHarmonica);

        holder.logo.setImageResource(harmonicaItem.logo);
        holder.button.setText(harmonicaItem.title);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        harmonicaItem.listView = holder.listView;
        harmonicaItem.button = holder.button;

        holder.listView.setTag(harmonicaItem);
        holder.button.setTag(harmonicaItem);

        row.setTag(holder);

        return row;
    }
```

The Model class

```
static class ListHolder {
    ImageView logo;
    TextView line;
    Button button;
    ListView listView;
}
```

How I retrieve the item

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    HarmonicaItem item = (HarmonicaItem) v.getTag();
}
```

layout of item inside gridview:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingLeft="115dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="loop"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/subHarmonica"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/buttonLayout"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

So a summary of my problem:
item.listView is sometimes null and sometimes the wrong listview.

My goal is to fill the listview and make it visible when you click the button.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Apparently I made a mistake in other code. When the listviews went back to gone I saved the listview. When I wanted it to show again it sometimes took the wrong list. So there is actually nothing wrong with the adapter.

Comment: how you are getting the ('v') view to retrieve tag. here=>'v.getTag()' ()

Comment: You are putting your ListView inside your ViewHolder? Even if it does work, that's a really horrible design.

Comment: @shobhan I set a onclicklistener on the gridview. The gridview contains HarmonicaItems

Comment: there you are putting ListHolder as tag. and getting HarmonicaItem.

Comment: can you plz define a little what do you mean by wrong listview ?

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper I want to make a listview visible when you click on a button. Each button has its own listview. How it works now is that sometimes the listview is null and sometimes I get the listview wich is from another button. I hope this makes it a little more clear

Answer (score 0):

Plz update your getView method

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null)
            {             
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder.logo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            holder.line = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line);
            holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.listView = (ListView)         holder.findViewById(R.id.subHarmonica); 
            holder.listView.setTag(harmonicaItem);
            holder.button.setTag(harmonicaItem);

     holder.setTag(holder);

            }

     else {
         holder = (ListHolder)row.getTag();
      }

            holder.logo.setImageResource(harmonicaItem.logo);
            holder.button.setText(harmonicaItem.title);
            holder.button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: I already tried to do it like that but it still gives the same problem

Comment: yes I already tried your answer but it gives me the same problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Some issue in your code
1. You miss the else part
2.need to Set tag inside if condition

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ListHolder holder;
        HarmonicaItem harmonicaItem = ((MainActivity) context).getHarmonicaItems().get(position);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
holder = new ListHolder();
        holder.logo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        holder.line = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line);
        holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button);
        holder.listView = (ListView) row.findViewById(R.id.subHarmonica);
 holder.listView.setTag(harmonicaItem);
        holder.button.setTag(harmonicaItem);

 row.setTag(holder);

        }else{
holder = (ListHolder)row.getTag();
}



        holder.logo.setImageResource(harmonicaItem.logo);
        holder.button.setText(harmonicaItem.title);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);






        return row;
    }
```

**Edit:**
I removed 2 lines of code in  that is

```
armonicaItem.listView = holder.listView;
        harmonicaItem.button = holder.button;
```

I think this is not needed. Try without this.

Comment: what a terrible idea(store View inside data item) **edit:** sorry, it was in original code

Comment: You mean this is wrong armonicaItem.listView = holder.listView;
        harmonicaItem.button = holder.button;

Comment: I tried your code, but I still got the same problem

Comment: `harmonicaItem.listView = holder.listView;` and the next line ...I though that you add it as fix ...

Comment: I understand i copy the code from the question check my edit. @Selvin

Comment: @Amsheer I tried your edit, but then I get a nullpointer because the listview is null

Comment: @Amsheer I updated my question a bit. Hope this will make it more clear

Comment: If you are using ListView inside of getView. I don't have answer. I am not sure what the output will come